# Вопрос по Аналоговым часам

Tags: android, время

товарищи. Нуждаюсь в помощи. Есть приложение, которое показывает аналоговые часы. Сейчас приложение использует системное время. Причем, как я понимаю, запрашивает его каждый раз при отрисовке стрелок. А мне нужно, чтобы время запрашивала программа 1 раз (из ntp сервера) и на основе этого времени часы продолжали работу. Не могу понять, как именно перестроить работу часов под мое условие. Нужно явно прописать угол, на который поворачивается каждая стрелка? Код работы часов прилагаю ниже (его самую важную часть).

```
     private void drawHand(Canvas canvas, double loc, boolean isHour, boolean isMinute) {
        double angle = Math.PI * loc / 30 - Math.PI / 2;
        int handRadius = 0;
        if (isHour) {
            handRadius = radius - handTruncation - hourHandTruncation;
        } else if (!isHour && isMinute) {
            handRadius = radius - handTruncation - minuteHandTruncation;
        } else {
            handRadius = radius - handTruncation;
        }

        canvas.drawLine(width / 2, height / 2,
                (float) (width / 2 + Math.cos(angle) * handRadius),
                (float) (height / 2 + Math.sin(angle) * handRadius), mPaint);
    }


    private void drawNumeral(Canvas canvas) {
        mPaint.setTextSize(fontSize);
        mPaint.setStrokeWidth(10);

        for (int number:
                numbers) {
            String tmp = String.valueOf(number);
            mPaint.getTextBounds(tmp, 0, tmp.length(), mRect);
            double angle = Math.PI / 6 * (number - 3);
            //Log.d("angle", String.valueOf(angle));
            int x = (int) (width / 2 + Math.cos(angle) * radius - mRect.width() / 2);
            int y = (int) (height / 2 + Math.sin(angle) * radius + mRect.height() / 2);
            canvas.drawText(tmp, x, y, mPaint);

        }
    }

    private void drawHands(Canvas canvas)  {
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        float hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        hour = hour > 12 ? hour - 12 : hour;
        drawHand(canvas, (hour * 5f + c.get(Calendar.MINUTE) * 5f / 60.0), true, false);
        drawHand(canvas, c.get(Calendar.MINUTE), false, true);
        drawHand(canvas, c.get(Calendar.SECOND), false, false);
    }
```

Comment: Непонятно как смена источника времени может влиять на его отображение. Замените `Calendar` на "свою" имплементацию источника времени и все. Любые часы это H:M:S

Comment: Немного вас не понял, прошу простить. Проблема в том, чтобы приложение не запрашивало время при каждой отрисовке стрелок, а запрашивало всего 1 раз, и, на основе полученного времени из ntp, рисовало стрелки. Вот с этим можете помочь? ну или хотя бы на нужную мысль натолкнуть.

Comment: Как раз мысль и есть в том, чтобы создать свои "часы", которые и будут обращаться к NTP, а не к Calendar. Чтобы самому не писать синхронизацию с NTP, есть готовые решения. К примеру https://github.com/lyft/Kronos-Android

Comment: "чтобы приложение не запрашивало время при каждой отрисовке стрелок" -- откуда оно узнает что стрелку пора передвигать, если у него не будет источника времени?